# Install postgresql10 on ubuntu20.04?

Tags: apt, postgresql

I upgraded ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

While I upgrade, I had to remove postgis library. (it wouldn't upgrade unless I delete it)

Now I have postgres10 without postgis, and I need postgis back on this db.

When I do `sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4` it says it can't install the package because dependency is not met..

Is it not possible to use postgresql-10 under ubuntu20.04?

Answer (score 0):

Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL has been updated from postgresql-10-postgis-2.4 to postgresql-12-postgis-3 in Ubuntu 20.04. To install postgresql-12-postgis-3 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-12-postgis-3
```

Installing postgresql-12-postgis-3 will also install postgresql-12 as a dependency, but it will not automatically install the postgis suggested package.

postgresql-12-postgis-3 adds support for geographic objects to the PostgreSQL object-relational database.

Comment: yeah, than I'll have to migrate data from pg 10 to pg 12

Comment: @eugene Installing postgresql-12-postgis-3 will also install postgresql-12 as a dependency. If this answer answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.